# Convert LocalDate to TimeStamp with UTC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, date

I am taking LocalDate as input and want to convert it into this format to search in oracle DB.

```
input - "2010-10-10"

Output- 10-OCT-10 07.39.02.713000000 AM UTC
```

I tried using TimeStamp and DateTime but getting date in these formats respectively.

```
2020-10-10 00:00:00.0 
2020-10-10T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

I used

```
Timestamp.valueOf(startDate.atStartOfDay());
DateTime.parse(startDate.toString());
```

Can you please help me? Thank you in advance

Updated.

Comment: "I tried using TimeStamp and DateTime" - please show us the code that you've been using.

Comment: Check documentation for DateTimeFormatter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Are you looking for java solution or oracle. You can use `sys_extract_utc(to_timestamp('2010-10-10','YYYY-MM-DD')) utc_time` if you are using oracle sql.

Comment: I can see that you have just edited your question. The same answer with the format, `dd-MMM-uu HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS a zzz` will work for your updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the given string to `LocalDate` and convert it into `ZonedDateTime` using [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2010-10-10");
        ZonedDateTime zdt = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS a zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(zdt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2010-10-10T00:00Z[Etc/UTC]
2010-10-10 00:00:00.000 AM UTC
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: @david use `DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S a zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);` format for your expected output.

Comment: @ArunkumarPushparaj - Yes, if he needs just one digit after the dot. I thought to change it but then left it thinking that he can adjust the number of `S`s as per his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass date and timestamp to oracle as strings (varchar2), just use bind variables of required data types: [oracle.sql.DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/DATE.html) or [oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html).

You can convert(cast) them in Oracle. Also you can change timezones using [SYS_EXTRACT_UTC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_EXTRACT_UTC.html), [TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ.html) or [AT TIME ZONE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-D8C7A7EB-A507-42A2-9B10-5301E822A7F2)